# HTML Generation using neo4jrestclient

Tags: html, neo4j, neo4jrestclient

So I was using the neo4jrestclient, and I noticed that in the class of QuerySequece, there's a .to_html()function (https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/blob/master/neo4jrestclient/query.py)
However, when I try using it I get the 'Unable to display the graph or the table' error.

I haven't found a working example of it. I was wondering if anyone has gotten this working.

Much thanks appreciated.

Comment: I think @versae uses that in iPython notebooks, but I'm not sure

Comment: @MichaelHunger is right. the `.to_html()` is only invoked inside a IPython Notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `.to_html()` is a function that IPython uses in order to render rich content inside Notebooks. When running inside a Notebook, `neo4jrestclient` asks for extra information to the Neo4j server, so it can draw the actual graph returned. Therefore, if you try to run a query inside an IPython Notebook, a D3 graph should be rendered automatically.

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase, Node, Relationship
gdb = GraphDatabase(url="http://localhost:7474")
gdb.query("MATCH (me)-[r]-() RETURN me, r LIMIT 10")
```

A running example can be seen in this [gist](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/versae/9826274). Although it's still a work in progress. I think that I could add an option to populate the needed fields in case you wanted to use the `.to_html()` outside the IPython Notebook. All you need to do is to make `neo4jrestclient` believe that it's running inside of one by modifying the function `neo4jrestclient.utils.in_ipnb()` making it to always return `True`. Let me know if you would use that feature and I will add it.

On the other hand, I am developing [`ipython-cypher`](https://github.com/versae/ipython-cypher), to have a better integration of IPython, Pandas, NetworkX, and matplotlib with Neo4j, but it's still in alpha.

**Update:** Now you can add [`data_contents=True`](https://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/queries.html#graph-and-row-data-contents) to return the extra data.

```
results = gdb.query(query, data_contents=True)
```

Data will be in `results.rows` and `results.graph`.